# Is await faster than then?

Tags: javascript, performance, promise

I know this sounds like a duplicate, BUT I have a small problem..

If I run the below code in nodeJS, `then` **ALWAYS** seems faster

**BUT** if I run the below code on a browser console, `await` **ALWAYS** seems faster

 Now When it runs here, they both seem **WAY FASTER** than browser console or node but `then` **ALWAYS** seems faster

Can someone tell me why it varies so much? I heard that `await` is faster but is that ONLY TRUE on a browser console? I'm honestly confused :{

**EDIT**: I added a snippet further below in which I try to show a *fair* example(I'm not sure if it is fair **BUT** `then` seems way faster)

```js
(async() => {
  //waiter function for promises
  function waiter(r, j) {
    r(1)
  }

  //await speed testing
  var d = new Date()
  for (let i = 0; i <= 999999; i++) {
    await new Promise(waiter)
  }
  let awaitSpeed = new Date() - d
  console.log(`speed for await is ${awaitSpeed}ms`)

  //then speed testing
  let d1 = new Date();
  let i = 0

  function _then(a) {
    if (i == 999999) {
      let thenSpeed = new Date() - d1
      return console.log(`speed for then is ${thenSpeed}ms`)
    }
    new Promise(waiter).then(_then);
    i++
  }
  new Promise(waiter).then(_then)
})()
```

**FAIR EXAMPLE ATTEMPT: `then` seems faster in all environments**

```js
(async() => {
  //waiter function for promises
  function waiter(r, j) {
    r(1)
  }

  //await speed testing
  var d = new Date(); let i1 = 0
  async function awaiter(n){
    if(n){return await new Promise(waiter)}
    i1++ //because of how await works, I CANNOT put it as the last thing to do
    if(i1 == 999999){
      //because of that, I MUST make up for the one await outstanding
      await awaiter(1)
      let awaitSpeed = new Date() - d
      return console.log(`speed for await is ${awaitSpeed}ms`)
    }
    await new Promise(waiter)
    return awaiter()
  }
  await awaiter()
  
  //then speed testing
  let d1 = new Date()
  let i = 0
  
  function _then(a) {
    if (i == 999999) {
      let thenSpeed = new Date() - d1
      return console.log(`speed for then is ${thenSpeed}ms`)
    }
    new Promise(waiter).then(_then)
    i++
  }
  new Promise(waiter).then(_then)
})()
```

Comment: The engine has some leeway to optimise `await` into whatever, while `.then` is a plain function call that must follow the usual function call paradigm. So yes, there's the potential for different runtimes. *How* exactly each engine does or doesn't optimise `await` will differ…

Comment: k thanks.. idc bout the minuses.. I just really needed to know(seems it's nothing I can do but still thanks)

Comment: It would probably help if these two were equivalent. Because right now it doesn't seem like they are. I'd be very wary drawing any conclusions from this test.

Comment: Also, in future, consider using `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` instead of Date? It may be more accurate

Comment: ok.. @VLAZ how would I make it equal then?

Comment: @VLAZ i tried to make a *fair* example.. any pointers?

Comment: @TheBombSquad it's hard to make an accurate test because you're currently not testing anything concrete.You're executing some code in a loop but with different semantics each time. Recursively applying `_then` with an `if` is very likely going to result in vastly different performance characteristics to a `for` loop. At the very least both would need to use the same control structures and iteration method. Likely a loop. Also, the `.then` test has more the function executions to `await` - it executes `new Promise`, `waiter`, `_then`, as well as the `.then()` method call.

Comment: So [this](https://jsbin.com/wuqofawepe/1/edit?js,console) would be a start. However, the execution time is still different which can still be down to different operations performed. As I said, there is nothing concrete tested here, so you're likely to see deviation because of assignments `p = p.then()` and other stuff not related to actually using either of these mechanisms. Dealing with mostly inconsequential actions (like `waiter` could also lead to optimisation taking place that you don't expect or account for. But even assuming that the results seen are "accurate" in as much as they

Comment: paint one of these approaches as faster *correctly*, then that still doesn't give you the full picture. Perhaps it's only faster *in this case* when executing *this code*. Things might change with any deviation, like `waiter` being anything different. Or a different number of loops. Or who knows. Micro-benchmarking without aim is not informative. In general, you need something to focus on *and* to test with realistic data to draw more valid conclusions. Finally, let's assume the results seen here are *accurate* and also *generally applicable*. When I've ran the test,

Comment: I'm getting 2062ms for `await` and 3397ms for `then`. That's a difference of 1.3 **micro**seconds between each. For anything that involves less than a million loops, this difference hardly matters.

Comment: To add a bit on @VLAZ's points on how meaningless this microbenchmarking is, simply switching the order in which both tests are performed returns different results: https://jsfiddle.net/skz1a85j/ What we can see though is how two different engines handle microtasks differently, in SpiderMonkey running only 99999 iterations (900000 less than in OP's snippet) it takes about a full second to perform any of these tests. In v8 on the same machine it takes 500ms to perform the full 999999 oO.

Comment: @Kaiido yep, changing the order could very well change the results because the JIT hasn't warmed up for the first test. Or it *has* but now has to change how it handles stuff for the second test.